# What type of visa do I have to apply in Singapore for taking part in an exhibition to sell garments

Tags: visas, singapore

I am planning to visit Singapore to take part in an exhibition for garment sale. What type of Visa is required.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Singapore

Answer (score 4):

According to https://www.mom.gov.sg/passes-and-permits/work-pass-exempt-activities/eligible-activities, a Short Term Visit Pass and a Work Pass Exemption is required to participate in any exhibition as an exhibitor https://www.mom.gov.sg/passes-and-permits/work-pass-exempt-activities/eligible-activities